# Using Custom Labels in a Class

Tags: apex, picklist, customlabel

I have the below If statements using some hard coded strings and I want to make them use as custom labels. I have created custom labels with the same String names as given below. So how can I make these statements to use the Custom Labels I created ?

```
if(monitoringFrequency == 'daily'){
            return dateValue.addDays(1);
        }else if(monitoringFrequency == 'weekly'){
            return dateValue.addDays(7);
        }else if(monitoringFrequency == 'monthly'){
            return dateValue.addMonths(1);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access these custom labels like this:

```
if(monitoringFrequency == System.Label.daily){
    return dateValue.addDays(1);
}else if(monitoringFrequency == System.Label.weekly){
    return dateValue.addDays(7);
}else if(monitoringFrequency == System.Label.monthly){
    return dateValue.addMonths(1);
}
```

Do make sure that the names of the custom labels are correct.

For more information, see: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm&language=en_US

Comment: If you want your code to be more terse you can omit the `System.` and just use `Label.` with no issues.

Comment: +1 for using `System.Label.[...]` consistently.   Helps to avoid debugging when also using a variable called `label` or another Apex Class called `Label`

Answer (score 4):

We can put label in salesforce these ways:

Visualforce Page:
`$Label.Label_API_Name`

Lightning Component Page
`{!$Label.c.Label_API_Name}`

Apex Class
`String getLabelName = Label.Label_API_Name;`

or directly
`System.Label.Label_API_Name`

hope this helps you.